# Несколько предложений в кавычках через запятую

Tags: пунктуация, прямая-речь

Нужно ли каждое новое предложение в кавычках писать с большой буквы?
Ставить ли точку в самом конце?

*«Это платье тебе не идет — возьми другое», «тебе нужно научиться ухаживать за своим телом», «зачем ты ешь столько калорийных продуктов - ты можешь поправиться. Хочешь фигуру как у меня?»*

Comment: Дайте более широкий контекст.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, пожалуйста, отметьте его [как принятый](/help/accepted-answer) (галочка рядом с ответом).

Answer (score 1):

Я бы предложила такой вариант.

[Каждый раз, когда я приезжала в гости к своим старшим сестрам, **они** меня настойчиво **поучали**]: ***«Это платье тебе не идет — возьми другое»; «Тебе нужно научиться ухаживать за своим телом»; «Зачем ты ешь столько калорийных продуктов? - ты можешь поправиться!"; "Хочешь фигуру как у меня?».***

Если это речь **одного** человека, то нет необходимости в таком огромном количестве кавычек.

[Каждый раз, когда я приезжала в гости к своей старшей сестре, **она** меня настойчиво **поучала**]: ***«Это платье тебе не идет — возьми другое... Тебе нужно научиться ухаживать за своим телом... Зачем ты ешь столько калорийных продуктов? - ты можешь поправиться!.. Хочешь фигуру как у меня?..».***

[**Вопросительный или восклицательный знак с многоточием**](https://orfogrammka.ru/%D0%BF%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%83%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F/%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8_%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BA_%D1%81_%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BC/)

Точка после кавычек в самом конце предложения необходима:
[**Пунктуация. Сочетание знаков препинания**](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/433714/%D0%9F%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%83%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%A1%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F)

**Дополнение** (как пример):

***Но звезды, как следовало из ее рассказа, не произвели на Рошель ни малейшего впечатления, потому что на каждое произнесенное имя она тут же ставила уничижительное клеймо: «Придурок он»; «Да у ней все искусственное»; «Эти — ни рыба ни мясо».***
[**Роберт Гэлбрейт, "Зов кукушки"**](http://loveread.me/read_book.php?id=25524&p=61)

Comment: По-моему, если фразы были произнесены одним человеком, но в разное время, то каждая фраза должна быть заключена в отдельные кавычки.

Comment: И еще. По-моему, каждое предложение должно начинаться с большой буквы.

Comment: @АлександрСтрелец (в продолжение стечения знаков) Посмотрите, Александр, у М_Г: _...Хочешь фигуру как у меня?»_ — без точки в конце. Это означает, что и слова автора должны быть с вопросительной интонацией. А это не так. Вопросительное предложение только одно. Переставьте его в середину — и точка после кавычек будет совершенно очевидна.

Answer (score 0):

В отсутствие контекста приходится домысливать. Например:

**Я постоянно слышу от нее: «Это платье тебе не идет — возьми другое», «Тебе нужно научиться ухаживать за своим телом», «Зачем ты ешь столько калорийных продуктов - ты можешь поправиться. Хочешь фигуру как у меня?»**

**А если это фраза от мамы, мы получаем рану на всю жизнь: «Это платье тебе не идет — возьми другое», «Тебе нужно научиться ухаживать за своим телом», «Зачем ты ешь столько калорийных продуктов - ты можешь поправиться. Хочешь фигуру как у меня?»**

Comment: Дело в том, что авторских слов нет...

Comment: А что есть? Какой контекст?

Comment: А если это фраза от мамы, мы получаем рану на всю жизнь.                    «Это платье тебе не идет — возьми другое», «тебе нудно научиться ухаживать за своим телом», «зачем ты ешь столько калорийных продуктов - ты можешь поправиться. Хочешь фигуру как у меня?»

Comment: Нужен еще более широкий контекст. Из того, что я понимаю пока, могу предположить, что "А если это фраза от мамы, мы получаем рану на всю жизнь" - это слова автора. После них можно поставить двоеточие - и далее как в моем ответе.

Comment: Благодарю за ответ