# Пунктуация. Сочетание знаков препинания

Tags: пунктуация

Такой вопрос: ставится ли точка после закрывающихся кавычек, если перед ними стоит многоточие, вопросительный и восклицательный знаки?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Есть такие ситуации.

Если перед закрывающей кавычкой стоит многоточие, вопросительный или восклицательный знаки (и на этом предложение заканчивается), то **те же знаки**, необходимые по условиям всего предложения, **не повторяются** после закрывающей кавычки:

*Помните ли вы у Маяковского: "А вы ноктюрн сыграть могли бы на флейте водосточных труб?"* (Вопросительное предложение со знаком вопроса в цитате.)

*Как я люблю есенинские строки: "Сыпь, гармоника! Сыпь, моя частая!"*
(Восклицательное предложение с восклицательным знаком в цитате.)

[**Разные знаки с кавычками**](https://orfogrammka.ru/%D0%BF%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%83%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F/%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B8_%D1%81_%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%87%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8/)

**Неодинаковые** же знаки, если они требуются в силу характера соответствующих частей текста, **могут ставиться перед закрывающими кавычками и после них** (в том числе и точка):

*Со школьной скамьи я помню: "А вы ноктюрн сыграть могли бы на флейте водосточных труб?".*
*В свое время не каждый мог прочитать: "Сыпь, гармоника! Сыпь, моя частая!
Пей, выдра! Пей!".*
*Фильм снят по мотивам неоконченной повести Василия Шукшина "А поутру они проснулись...".*
[**О сочетаниях знаков препинания**](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/rules/165-oszp)

Comment: Римма, интересует материал последней ссылки (Грамота). Там есть такие примеры: Я спрашиваю: «Но как же тогда?» Пожал плечами и сказал: «Сие для меня тайна!» Скажите, пожалуйста, почему не стоят точки после кавычек? Потому что это чистая прямая речь, а в Ваших примерах в ответе - нет?

Comment: Совершенно верно, потому что это прямая речь. Примеры, которые приведены мной,  — это цитирование. Сравните: _Со школьной скамьи я помню_ — повествовательное предложение; _А вы ноктюрн сыграть могли бы на флейте водосточных труб?_ — вопросительное. Вывод: в конце предложения (после вопр. цитаты) необходима точка.

Comment: Спасибо. На этот вопрос я перешел с недавно поднятого вопроса "Несколько предложений в кавычках через запятую", и там Вы ставите точки после гипотетического "...она поучала:...". Не пойму - это не прямая речь? В другом ответе, у М_Г, точек нет.

Comment: Это прямая речь. Но смысл в том, что внутренних предложений несколько и они "разнознаковые".

Comment: Понятно, спасибо еще раз!

Comment: В последнем предложении точка не нужна. Да и в предпоследнем тоже. [Тут](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/4222/%d0%a1%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f-%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d1%82%d0%be%d1%87%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b5-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%b2%d1%8b%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4-%d0%ba%d0%be%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d1%8b%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d1%81%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b8%d1%82-%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%b2%d0%be%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%86) был ответ Бегемотуса с цитатой.

Comment: @АртёмЛуговой  С предпоследним согласен. И в первом тоже бы убрал точку. А вот в последнем оставил бы, так как название повести хоть и является законченным предложением, но это название. Точно так же, как и в пресловутом примере:  Драматический кружок готовит к постановке пьесу «В бой!».